# Starting with Corona Enterprise Plugin Development

Tags: android, coronasdk

I need to integrate a third party Java library which has come with a .jar with a Corona app.
I am developing an Android app, and I have Corona Enterprise.

I have been referring to [this doc](http://docs.coronalabs.com/native/plugin/index.html#java) to create a plugin for Corona, but so far can't understand how to start with it.

My knowledge of Corona is pretty basic, and I have followed [this video tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x1DcMVSXzBE) to get started with development.

A summary of what I can't understand:

- If I create an application, what folder structure should I create?
- Where should I put the .jar file?
- Where should I put those .so files?
- Where should I put the Lua bridge after I create it?
- Is there a sample Plugin that I can see and learn from?

Answer (score 1):

This guide should give you more info: http://docs.coronalabs.com/native/android/index.html

Answer (score 1):

There will be an folder in your Corona Enterprise,

CoronaEnterprise/ProjectTemplates/App/android

You should follow it to see complete structure of basic app. for your implementation.

Also I would suggest, If you have Corona Enterprise licence. Then please follow read me files available in Corona Enterprise folder. IT has all the details and reference links which helps us from begin to end. It helps me a lot in IOS plugin development.